# How to convert promise method to rxjs Observables in angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am new to typescript and angular and observables. My question is I have this method that takes a URL and returns the favicon of that URL. How can I use observables instead of promise

```
 getFavIcon(url: string): Promise<any> {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const hostname = this.getDomain(url);
        const src = 'http://' + hostname + '/favicon.ico';

        const image = new Image();
        image.onerror = () => {
            reject({ hasFavourite: false });

        };
        image.onload = () => {
            resolve({ hasFavourite: true, imageURL: src});
        };
        image.src = src;
      });
  }
```

Comment: `import {Observable} from 'rxjs'; return new Observable(observer => {  image.onload = () => {
            observer.next({ hasFavourite: true, imageURL: src});
        }; });` etc.

Comment: Hi Aluan Haddad, Thank you for the reply I did import the observable. I wanted to subscribe it  can i do getFavIcon(url).subscribe({next:(

this is the implementation i have when i use promise.
      this.getFavIcon(this.contentLink.url).then((res) => {
        this.favIconUrl = res.imageURL;
        this.hasFavIcon = true;
      }).catch((err) => {
      });

Comment: And also just wondering to ask is it a good practice to use observables all the time and forget about promise ?

Comment: No. It's a bad practice to always use observables. Specifically, in cases such as yours where at most one value will ever be emitted by the observable, promises are a perfect fit and express your intent more clearly. Furthermore, promises support the `async`/`await` syntax which obviates the need for callbacks and allows you to write very clean code. Finally, you can create an observable from a promise using RxJS utility functions like `from` as well as flattening operators like `mergeMap` so mixing promises into observable code is easy.

Comment: Hi @AluanHaddad, Thank you so much for the explanation. I was in a confusion to change from promise to observable. This clears all of it, a very detailed explanation thank you again  :)

Comment: No problem. Good luck and have fun

Answer (score 3):

Its creation is quite similar to promise apart from observable can be a continuous stream and you have `complete()` it to behave like Promise

```
 getFavIcon(url: string): Promise<any> {
      return new Observable((obs) => {
        const hostname = this.getDomain(url);
        const src = 'http://' + hostname + '/favicon.ico';

        const image = new Image();
        image.onerror = () => {
            obs.error({ hasFavourite: false });

        };
        image.onload = () => {
            obs.next({ hasFavourite: true, imageURL: src});
            obs.complete()
        };
        image.src = src;
      });
  }
```